# Simular Backspacing en c++

Tags: c++, bucles, pilas

necesito de su ayuda para resolver un problema,
consiste en crear un programa que lea una cadena de texto entre 1 y 10^9 y un numero numero entre  1 y 10^9

La función del teclado de tu computadora es agregar caracteres al final de una cadena de texto al momento de presionar cualquiera de sus teclas. Sin embargo, la tecla backspace no tiene la misma función. Esta tecla elimina el último caracter que se encuentra en la cadena.

De este modo, si presionas N veces la tecla backspace, se borrarán N caracteres de la cadena o toda la cadena si su longitud es menor a N.

Ejemplo
**Entrada**
Anita lava la tina
3

**Salida**
Anita lava la t

ya lo intenté pero el juez de la plataforma Omegaupp dice que lo resuelve solo al 83%,
https://omegaup.com/arena/problem/Backspacing/
ese es el link del problema

Esta  fue mi primera solución

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
    using namespace std;
    
    struct Nodo
    {
        char dato;
        Nodo *siguiente;
    };
    
    void agregarPila(Nodo *&,char);
    void sacarPila(Nodo *&,char &);
    
    int main()
    {
        Nodo *pila = NULL;
        char cad[1000];
        int longitud = 0, i = 0, n = 0;
        
        cin.getline(cad, 1000,'\n');
        longitud = strlen(cad);
        
        for(i = 0; i<longitud; i++)
        {
            agregarPila(pila, cad[i]);
        }
        cin>>n;
        for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            sacarPila(pila,cad[longitud-1]);
            longitud--;
        }
        
        for(i = 0; i<longitud; i++)
        {
            cout<<cad[i];
        }             
                                                                                                    
        return 0;
    }
    
    void agregarPila(Nodo *&pila,char n)
    {
    Nodo *nuevo_nodo = new Nodo();
    nuevo_nodo->dato = n;
    nuevo_nodo->siguiente = pila;
    pila = nuevo_nodo;
    }
    
    void sacarPila(Nodo *&pila,char &n)
    {
    Nodo *aux = pila;
    n = aux->dato;
    pila = aux->siguiente;
    delete aux;
    }
```

pero solo cumple lo propuesto al 66%

Esta es mi segunda solucion, sin usar pilas

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    string cadena;
    getline(cin, cadena);
    cin>>n;
    cadena.resize (cadena.length()-n);
    cout<<cadena;
    return 0;
}
```

pero solo cumple con el 83%,
agradeceria su ayuda, ya investigue bastante y no logro dar con la solución

Comment: ¿Podrías decirnos cuál es el motivo por el que el sitio te dice eso?

Answer (score 0):

En el problema te esta diciendo que si la longitud es menor a N borrar toda la cadena, entonces si restas la longitud - N y N es mas grande que la longitud te puede dar un numero **negativo**, al calcular el nuevo tamaño estas haciendo la operación con cadena.length() que es un size_t y n que es un int, entonces se esta haciendo una conversión implícita de n a size_t y el resultado es almacenado en un size_t que es un entero sin **signo**, las operaciones aritméticas en enteros sin signo se calculan así (longitud - N) modulo (2 elevado a la x) donde x es el numero de bits de size_t, por ejemplo en mi maquina es de 32 bits entonces si longitud = 2 y N = 10 el resultado seria (-8) modulo (2 elevado a la 32) que es igual a 4294967288, entonces no estaría reduciendo el tamaño si no **aumentando**, para corregir este comportamiento dejo el siguiente código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::cin.tie(nullptr);
  std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);

  int n { 0 };
  std::string cadena{ };
  std::getline(std::cin, cadena);
  std::cin >> n;

  size_t resize { 0u };
  // un int puede ser menor que un size_t
  if (n < cadena.length()) {
    // ya que n es menor podemos restar sin tener problemas de signo
    resize = cadena.length() - n;
  }
  cadena.resize(resize);
  std::cout<<cadena;

  return 0;
}
```

PD: puedes leer mas sobre conversiones implícitas [aquí](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion)

Comment: estoy agradecido, me sirvió bastante para poder resolver el problema